# Beamer : what are the back, find, forward hyperlink commands?

Tags: beamer, navigation

I look for back, find and forward commands, like this set of commands :

```
\hyperlinkslideprev{texte du lien} : va à la couche prédédente ;
\hyperlinkslidenext{texte du lien} : va à la couche suivante ;
\hyperlinkframestart{texte du lien} : va à la première couche de la page en cours ;
\hyperlinkframeend{texte du lien} : va à la dernière couche de la page en cours ;
\hyperlinkframestartnext{texte du lien} : va à la première couche de la page suivante ;
\hyperlinkframeendprev{texte du lien} : va à la dernière couche de la page précédente.
Dans ces 4 commandes, on peut remplacer frame par section ou subsection.
\hyperlinkpresentationstart{texte du lien} : va à la première couche de la présentation ;
\hyperlinkpresentationend{texte du lien} : va à la dernière couche de la présentation ( ne va pas dans les annexes) ;
\hyperlinkappendixstart{texte du lien} : va à la première couche des annexes (ou dernière couche de la présentation s'il n'y a pas d'annexes) ;
\hyperlinkappendixend{texte du lien} : va à la dernière couche des annexes ;
\hyperlinkdocumentstart{texte du lien} : va à la première couche de la présentation ;
\hyperlinkdocumentend{texte du lien} : va à la dernière couche de la présentation (dans les annexes si elles existent) ;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for...

Comment: As usual ;-) Here is a list of all hypermink macro I found and some of them are used in the naviagation bar. But in the navigation bar there are three buttons backward, forward, and find that on can insert in the bar using `\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol`. I look for this commands separatly, like the list above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands associated with the back, find and forward navigation in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) are "Acrobat-specific *hyperlinks*". [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides access to these functions via

```
\Acrobatmenu{<menu option>}{<text>}
```

From section **5 Acrobat-specific behavior** in the [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html):

> If you want to access the menu options of Acrobat Reader or Exchange, the following macro is provided in the appropriate drivers:
>
> ```
> \Acrobatmenu{<menu option>}{<text>}
> ```
>
> The `text` is used to create a button which activates the appropriate `menu option`. The following table lists the option names you can use - comparison of this with the menus in Acrobat Reader or Exchange will show what they do. Obviously some are only appropriate to Exchange.
>
> - File
>
>   `Open`, `Close`, `Scan`, `Save`, `SaveAs`, `Optimizer:SaveAsOpt`, `Print`, `PageSetup`, `Quit`
> - File→Import
>
>   `ImportImage`, `ImportNotes`, `AcroForm:ImportFDF`
> - File→Export
>
>   `ExportNotes`, `AcroForm:ExportFDF`
> - File→DocumentInfo
>
>   `GeneralInfo`, `OpenInfo`, `FontsInfo`, `SecurityInfo`, `Weblink:Base`, `AutoIndex:DocInfo`
> - File→Preferences
>
>   `GeneralPrefs`, `NotePrefs`, `FullScreenPrefs`, `Weblink:Prefs`, `AcroSearch:Preferences` (Windows) or, `AcroSearch:Prefs` (Mac), `Cpt:Capture`
> - Edit
>
>   `Undo`, `Cut`, `Copy`, `Paste`, `Clear`, `SelectAll`, `Ole:CopyFile`, `TouchUp:TextAttributes`, `TouchUp:FitTextToSelection`, `TouchUp:ShowLineMarkers`, `TouchUp:ShowCaptureSuspects`, `TouchUp:FindSuspect`, `Properties`
> - Edit→Fields
>
>   `AcroForm:Duplicate`, `AcroForm:TabOrder`
> - Document
>
>   `Cpt:CapturePages`, `AcroForm:Actions`, `CropPages`, `RotatePages`, `InsertPages`, `ExtractPages`, `ReplacePages`, `DeletePages`, `NewBookmark`, `SetBookmarkDest`, `CreateAllThumbs`, `DeleteAllThumbs`
> - View
>
>   `ActualSize`, `FitVisible`, `FitWidth`, `FitPage`, `ZoomTo`, `FullScreen`, `FirstPage`, `PrevPage`, `NextPage`, `LastPage`, `GoToPage`, `GoBack`, `GoForward`, `SinglePage`, `OneColumn`, `TwoColumns`, `ArticleThreads`, `PageOnly`, `ShowBookmarks`, `ShowThumbs`
> - Tools
>
>   `Hand`, `ZoomIn`, `ZoomOut`, `SelectText`, `SelectGraphics`, `Note`, `Link`, `Thread`, `AcroForm:Tool`, `Acro_Movie:MoviePlayer`, `TouchUp:TextTool`, `Find`, `FindAgain`, `FindNextNote`, `CreateNotesFile`
> - Tools→Search
>
>   `AcroSrch:Query`, `AcroSrch:Indexes`, `AcroSrch:Results`, `AcroSrch:Assist`, `AcroSrch:PrevDoc`, `AcroSrch:PrevHit`, `AcroSrch:NextHit`, `AcroSrch:NextDoc`
> - Window
>
>   `ShowHideToolBar`, `ShowHideMenuBar`, `ShowHideClipboard`, `Cascade`, `TileHorizontal`, `TileVertical`, `CloseAll`
> - Help
>
>   `HelpUserGuide`, `HelpTutorial`, `HelpExchange`, `HelpScan`, `HelpCapture`, `HelpPDFWriter`, `HelpDistiller`, `HelpSearch`, `HelpCatalog`, `HelpReader`, `Weblink:Home`
> - Help (Windows)
>
>   `About`

To see which Acrobat menus are accessed, have a look at the macro `\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol` (from [`beamerbasenavigation.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasenavigation.sty)):

```
\def\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{-1.5pt}{20pt}{5.5pt}
    \pgfuseobject{beamerbackfindforwardnav}%
  \end{pgfpicture}\kern-20pt%
  \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\beamer@linkspace{7pt}}%
  \Acrobatmenu{Find}{\beamer@linkspace{6pt}}%
  \Acrobatmenu{GoForward}{\beamer@linkspace{7pt}}}
```

The Acrobat actions used are `GoBack`, `Find` and `GoForward`.